# Foreign Key & Entity Framework Relational Design

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two tables in my SQL database currently in question. The first, `MasterPartsList` is just the entry point of all the partnumbers in our system, given by the property`pn`. The second table, `MasterPartsLists` contains parent-child (Bill of Material) information for *assemblies* in MasterPartsList, given by the properties:

`parentAssyPn` 
and `pn`, which is the foreign key from `MasterPartNumbers`.

Two Tables look like:

```
 MasterPartNumbers (parent) one -> many     MasterPartsLists (children)
 (PK) pn                                    (fk) pn
      desc                                       parentAssemblyPn  (could also be a fk)
                                                 qty
                                                 price
```

This leads me to question 1:

Q1: for Top Level Assembly part numbers in `MasterPartsList`, should I

a. leave the `parentAssyPn` `NULL`, and just populate `pn` with the assembly part number in question, and have no primary key in the table

b. set `parentAssyPn` = `pn` and create a `partial key` using parentAssyPn`and`pn`?

Q2: In either of the two cases, how will this effect how I am able to save my Entity Framework entity data back to the database appropriately (to the two tables) from my application in which I expose the data from `ObservableCollection`s?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question.  Can you provide a few rows of example data?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Bobson -- hope the addition of the table examples helps :)

Comment: For Q1, I say "leave parentAssyPn null, and make pn the primary key" I don't know about Q2, though.

Comment: The only thing hanging me up is that pn cannot be the primary key as it will appear multiple times in the table, just under different parentAssyPns. I read that Entity Framework will make this table readonly if I do not have a primary key defined at all, even if it is not one of the properties I am interested in setting the value of.

Comment: UB3571 - So each part can be part of multiple other parts?  In that case, I'd make `(pn, parentAssyPn)` the primary key, so each *combination* only appears once.

Comment: @Bobson, but did you read my comment about parentAssyPn being null when the assembly has no parent (i.e. it is the top-most assembly)?

Comment: You're right, I'd forgotten that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to change the data model?

If a part in the MasterPartsLists can appear the child for more than one MasterPartNumbers, then is a many-to-many relationship.

I suggest the following tables:

> **Part**
>
> PartNumber (PK)
>
> Desc
>
> Price

and

> **Assembly**
>
> Parent_pn (PK)(FK)
>
> PartNumber (PK)
>
> qty

Your full parts inventory is stored in the Parts table.
You don't store any Top Level Assemblies in the Assembly table.

For table Assembly, read it as:
To assemble part {Parent_pn}, I need {qty} items of {PartNumber}. (Repeat as necessary to finish assembling Parent_pn.)

EDIT:
Let's try a simple example where a pen consists of colored ink, a barrel and a cap.

Your Part table would look like:

> 1, Red Pen
>
> 2, Blue Pen
>
> 3, red ink
>
> 4, blue ink
>
> 5, barrel
>
> 6, cap

Assembly:

> 1, 3, 1 -- Red pen needs red ink
>
> 1, 5, 1 -- Red pen needs one barrel
>
> 1, 6, 1 -- Red pen needs one cap
>
> 2, 4, 1 -- Blue pen needs blue ink
>
> 2, 5, 1 -- Blue pen needs one barrel
>
> 2, 6, 1 -- Blue pen needs one cap

Using this example, we can see that this is a many to many relationship:
- A Master part (e.g. Red Pen) is made up of many components.
- A component (e.g. cap) can be used to make up many master parts.

Could this apply to your scenario?

Comment: Thanks so much @chabzjo. What do you suggest for me in case of a top-level assembly, which has no parent? If it is to be part of the "composite" (or "partial") key, it will have no parent_pn. This leaves me with my only option of making parent_pn = pn (itself). Is this the accepted way of doing things? Also, just to be sure-- are you sure that you've taken into account that the same PartNumber could belong to multiple Parent_pns? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: The thing I know for certain: There is only one way to make an assembly.

Comment: Added sample data to my original answer to demonstrate how tables would be used.

Comment: Good morning, Chabzjo -- I apologize for being so dense yesterday. Everything you said made perfect sense after some rest. Very concise/fantastic answer. Thank you so much :)

Comment: One more question now that my brain is in order: should I also create a navigation relationship within the MasterPartsList table between the parentPnID and pnID? (some parents are actually children of other parents/ some children are parents of other children.) And if so, what direction should I be interpreting the navigation?

Comment: I’m from the school of thought that you should always create relationships in the database. Once they’re in the db, you can navigate either way: A Master part (e.g. Red Pen) is made up of many components. - A component (e.g. cap) can be used to make up many master parts.
The actual relationship in the database is 
`Part.PartNumber  (1) <---> (n) Assembly.Parent_pn` (Note that the database will only accept this relationship if Assembly's primary key is concatenated as described above or a surrogate key (a system generated id).)